# PyQt5 mousetracking not working

Tags: python, mouseevent, python-3.4, pyqt5, qpushbutton

I've found an example that changing a QPushButton's icon when mouse is hover on it. I tried to convert it to my codes, but there are some problems. First check the example I found, it's really short. http://paste.ubuntu.com/17302717/

These codes changing the icon of button if mouse is on it. Here is my codes that raises error

> return QPushButton.mouseMoveEvent(QPushButton, event)
>   TypeError: QPushButton.mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent): first argument of unbound method must have type 'QPushButton'

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QPushButton,QWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize

import PyQt5.QtWidgets,PyQt5.QtCore,sys



class cssden(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.mwidget = QMainWindow(self)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        self.setMouseTracking(True)

        self.setFixedSize(1400,923)


        #Button
        self.mbutton = QPushButton(self)
        self.mbutton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(30,30,30);"
                                   "background-image: url('resources/twitter-logo.png');"
                                   "border: 3px solid black;"
                                   "background-position: center;"
                                   )
        self.mbutton.setGeometry(2,300,110,60)
        self.mbutton.clicked.connect(self.yaz)

        self.show()
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):

        if event.pos().x()>self.mbutton.width()-10 or event.pos().y()>self.mbutton.height()-10\
                    or event.pos().x() < 10 or event.pos().y()< 10:
            bmp = QIcon("1.png")
            self.mbutton.setIcon(bmp)

        else:
            bmp = QIcon('2.png')
            self.mbutton.setIcon(bmp)
        self.mbutton.setIconSize(QSize(200,200))
        return QPushButton.mouseMoveEvent(self, event)

    def yaz(self):
        print ("button pressed")

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setStyleSheet("QMainWindow{background-color: rgb(30,30,30);border: 2px solid rgb(20,20,20)}")

ex = cssden()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I don't understand where is the problem. I tried to change `return QPushButton.mouseMoveEvent(self, event)` to `return QPushButton.mouseMoveEvent(QPushButton, event)` and other versions, but not worked. What I'm missing, how can I fix this?

**EDIT**: I changed `self.setMouseTracking(True)` to `self.mbutton.setMouseTracking(True)` and no error now, but icon is not changing anyway. Why the icon is not changing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has a few problems, namely with imports. The main problem though is that you don't need this: `return QPushButton.mouseMoveEvent(self, event)`

Try the following corrections to your code:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QPushButton,QWidget from
PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize from PyQt5
import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

import PyQt5.QtWidgets,PyQt5.QtCore,sys

class cssden(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # self.mwidget = QMainWindow(self)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        self.setMouseTracking(True)

        self.setFixedSize(1400,923)


        #Button
        self.mbutton = QPushButton(self)
        self.mbutton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(30,30,30);"
                                   "background-image: url('resources/twitter-logo.png');"
                                   "border: 3px solid black;"
                                   "background-position: center;"
                                   )
        self.mbutton.setGeometry(2,300,110,60)
        self.mbutton.clicked.connect(self.yaz)

        self.show()
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):

        if event.pos().x()>self.mbutton.width()-10 or event.pos().y()>self.mbutton.height()-10\
                    or event.pos().x() < 10 or event.pos().y()< 10:
            bmp = QIcon("1.png")
            self.mbutton.setIcon(bmp)
        else:
            print(1)
            bmp = QIcon('2.png')
            self.mbutton.setIcon(bmp)
        self.mbutton.setIconSize(QSize(200,200))
        # return self.mbutton.mouseMoveEvent(event)

    def yaz(self):
        print ("button pressed")

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setStyleSheet("QMainWindow{background-color:
rgb(30,30,30);border: 2px solid rgb(20,20,20)}")

ex = cssden() sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

In any case, I don't really understood what you are trying to achieve. If you need to create some kind of hover effect to your button there are other, much better ways. For example this one:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QPushButton,QWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

import PyQt5.QtWidgets,PyQt5.QtCore,sys

class HoverButton(QPushButton):
    mouseHover = QtCore.pyqtSignal(bool)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QPushButton.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)

    def enterEvent(self, event):
        self.mouseHover.emit(True)
        bmp = QIcon("1.png")
        self.setIcon(bmp)
        self.setIconSize(QSize(200,200))

    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        self.mouseHover.emit(False)
        bmp = QIcon("2.png")
        self.setIcon(bmp)
        self.setIconSize(QSize(200,200))

class cssden(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # self.mwidget = QMainWindow(self)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        self.setMouseTracking(True)

        self.setFixedSize(1400, 923)


        #Button
        self.mbutton = HoverButton(self)
        self.mbutton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(30,30,30);"
                                   "background-image: url('resources/twitter-logo.png');"
                                   "border: 3px solid black;"
                                   "background-position: center;"
                                   )
        self.mbutton.setGeometry(2,300,110,60)
        self.mbutton.clicked.connect(self.yaz)
        self.show()

    def yaz(self):
        print("button pressed")

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setStyleSheet("QMainWindow{background-color: rgb(30,30,30);border: 2px solid rgb(20,20,20)}")

ex = cssden()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I would advise the following answers:

[PyQT how to make a QEvent.Enter on QPushbutton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921472/pyqt-how-to-make-a-qevent-enter-on-qpushbutton) (my solution is based on this method)

[Pyqt Mouse hovering on a QPushButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27508552/pyqt-mouse-hovering-on-a-qpushbutton)

Comment: Your first example is not working, but second one is doing what I want. So I have to make another class `class HoverButton(QPushButton)` and use it in my codes?

Comment: @GLHF I can assure both are working since I've tested them before posting. Notice working does not mean working well. As I said I has some difficulty in understanding what your were trying to do. In any case the answer is Yes: the best way, from my point of view, is subclassing the QPushButton.

Comment: This can be achieved using setStyleSheet(QPushButton:hover{image:url(<image path>)})